# Trying to do ssh authentication with key files: server refused our key

Tags: server, ssh, authentication

I'm trying to setup ssh authentication with key files in stead of username/password. The client is a Windows box running PuTTY and the server is a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server.

I downloaded puttygen.exe and had it generate a key pair. In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I have this line:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

and on my client's public key file it says this:

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "my@email.address.com"
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIEAr3Qo6T5XU06ZigGOd3eKvfBhFLhg5kWv8lz6
qJ2G9XCbexlPQGanPhh+vcPkhor6+7OmB+WSdHeNO652kTofnauTKcTCbHjsT7cJ
GNrO8WVURRh4fabknUHPmauerWQZ6TgRPGaz0aucU+2C+DUo2SKVFDir1vb+4u83
AV1pKxs=my@email.address.com
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

I copied the part from "ssh-rsa AAA" to "my@email.address.com" and put that in the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on my server (in my own homefolder). In PuTTY under Connection > SSH > Auth I entered the path to the private key it generated on my client and saved the session settings.

I restarted the ssh server with

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Now if I load the profile in PuTTY (I verified the private key is still in Connection > SSH > Auth and that the path is correct) and run the profile, it says

```
Server refused our key
```

I tried putting the public key in a file under the **directory** `./ssh/authorized_keys/` but that didn't help so I used `./ssh/authorized_keys` as a **file**, pasting the key in it. I also tried generating a private/public key pair on the server, putting the public key in `./ssh/authorized_files` and loading the private one in PuTTY on my client. Rebooting the server didn't help either.

I found that the error may be solved by putting the key in a place outside the user's home folder but that's only useful if the home folder is encrypted, which this one is not.

Also tried generating a 4096 bit key, thinking perhaps 1024 was too short.

How can I get this to work? Thanks!

### EDIT:

Ok, `/var/log/auth.log` said:

```
sshd: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/vorkbaard/.ssh
```

Google tells me `~/.ssh/` should be 700 and and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` should be 600, so I did that. Now `/var/log/auth.log` says:

```
sshd: error: key_read: uudecode AAAAB3N [etc etc etc until about 3/4 of my public key]
```

Comment: `/var/log/auth.log` helps a lot, thanks =)

Comment: +1 for checking /var/log/auth.log.  I had an unrelated problem, but checking that log file helped me solve it.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Ok, it is fixed however I don't see how this is different from what I tried already.

What I did:

- generate a key pair with puttygen.exe (length: 1024 bits)
- load the private key in the PuTTY profile
- enter the public key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` **in one line**
  (`ssh-rsa {your_public_key}` with no more than once space between `ssh-rsa` and your key)
- `chmod 700 ~/.ssh`
- `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- `chown $USER:$USER ~/.ssh -R`
- change `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` so it contains `AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- `sudo service ssh restart`

For troubleshooting do `# tail -f /var/log/auth.log`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm, so what happened to that `sshd: error: key_read: uudecode AAAAB3N` error in `auth.log`?

Comment: I haven't a clue, Alaa. Perhaps I made an error pasting the previous key string. Auth.log doesn't get any more entries now and key based authentication works flawlessly. My main problem was that I wasn't really sure about **what** needed to be done, making the **how** that much more difficult. So I don't know why but it works. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: Awesome!!! I have been scratching my head for 2 days. This answers saves the day!!

Comment: Step 3 was the trick for me. I didn't put the public key in the `authorized_keys` file I just pasted my `mykey.pub` file into the `~/.ssh` folder and thought it would pick it up. Instead what I needed ultimately was to run this or edit and paste in below other keys that may be in there. `cat mykey.pub >> authorized_keys`. Seems simple now, but lesson learned is all public keys have to live in `authorized_keys` not just in the `~/.ssh/` directory. Someone please advise if this is not a correct assertion.

Comment: if the steps doesn't help, check also:
1. you copied the saved PuTTY public key into authorized_keys, not the OpenSSH one
2. if you copied using copy/paste from PuTTYgen (which you should do), you may have split the public key in multiple lines; it should be a single line; make sure you did not add leading or trailing spaces while copying

thanks to r_hartman
https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=990

Comment: I would add 
`chmod go-w ~/`

Comment: This post was very helpful, but I need to change the format of my public key to start with ```ssh-rsa XYZASDF```... to make it work. I used the button "Save Public Key" and it was saved in a different format.

Comment: Seems default length in PuttyGen is now 2048. Your comment of (length 1024) solved it for me. Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean: "sudo service sshd restart"-- not ssh

Comment: I'm having problems...i can access with root just ok, but i try to access with my user (nott) i have problems...serve refuse my keys, a few debugging shows me "failed publickey for nott" and my path is just like yours with %h before

Comment: Another reason it happens is with encrypted home directories, where before an interactive login occurs, the user's home directory is still encrypted and inaccessible.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. Just to note, I notice this happening a lot on Raspian Jessie. For some reason, this line is commented out by default.

Comment: This step did the trick for me: `chown $USER:$USER ~/.ssh -R`

Comment: I also needed to add `chmod 755 ~`  but I think I specifically needs non group/other write access

Comment: What does `chown $USER:$USER ~/.ssh -R` do? Do I need to substitute my actual username/login?

Comment: Figured out two main things in /etc/ssh/sshd_config: uncomment `AuthorizedKeysFile` line and line `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-dss`.

Comment: This is the golden checklist. Go down this list and one of them should fix it. Usually its permissions or rather the folder isn't owned by the user. Its very picky about the permissions. The .ssh folder and the authorized_keys file need to match the permissions on the list (700 and 600 as listed). The user you are connecting with needs to own the folder. Remember its chown username:group ~/.ssh -R. -R does all subfolders and will blanket everything below.

Comment: Man, hours and hours I have been messing with this. I know this is old but it still works! Thanks a million

Comment: Adding the public key to the second line inside host .ssh/authorized_keys, then save, worked for me.  Excellent!  Thank you.

Comment: Just to add a helpful comment for future visitors : I just had an SSH key weirdly just stop working for me, threw me a complete curve ball.  Looked in auth.log and it told me the user permissions on my HOME folder where wrong, NOT .ssh or the auth keys file, and when I did an "ls -al" in my ~ folder, sure enough the entry for '.' had gotten corrupted somehow, as soon as I did a "chown myname:users ." and corrected it, SSH started to work with it's existing key again.

Answer (score 34):

I just encountered this problem. Despite having the config set correctly as is already mentioned in this thread (permissions on authorized_keys etc.), it turns out I had the public key in the wrong format. It was in the form of:

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "imported-openssh-key"
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDUoj0N3vuLpeviGvZTasGQ...
... lPmTrOfVTxI9wjax2JvKcyE0fiNMzXO7qiHJsQM9G9ZB4Lkf71kT
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

Which wasn't working. But got it working having it in the form:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDU.....j0N3vuLpeviGvZTasGQa1rcJiPXQMW7v3uurb+n94B9MQaaWR0odsg5DJQL92TNenOda5BO1nd08y6+sdLQmHXExTz6X8FzgoVsAkEl3RscxcxHUksiKA9JfTo38vQvG/bPxIHMCuSumCQVA1laf3rO/uOrkcB7iMWhaoi1/z6AbFtPzeh7xjGfInMWwtBI0CsHSRF73VWIxT26w0P+KjafCjSn/7vDO1bT8QHujSQelU/GqaVEvbbvPl1a7POVjKgHLNekolwRKfNeVEewcnmZaoqfHgOKlPmTrOfVTxI9wjax2JvKcyE0fiNMzXO7qiHJsQM9G9ZB4Lkf71kT UserName@HOSTNAME
```

Comment: You can use `ssh-keygen -i -f filenameofwindowsformpub.key` to transform the public key into the format understood by your OpenSSH server.

Comment: Yes, it worked for me! It has to be in a single line. Can't believe it was only that!

Comment: HI kuraara I reckon the above instruction by @Black should be made prominent in the answer.

Comment: Can I add comment to OpenSSH server format? For human it is hard to tell what computer this key represent.

Comment: When I follow the suggestion by @Black, there is no UserName@HOSTNAME at the end of the string.  I don't know if that part matters.

Comment: the "ssh-keygen -i -f" worked for me

Answer (score 13):

I had to change permissions to home directory

```
chmod 700 ~
```

Comment: This worked for me as well (on AIX though).

Comment: Worked for me on CentOS as well

Comment: Worked for me on Redhat! Group write access seems to be the specific issue. Still works for me if I leave group read permissions in place though:  "chmod 740 ~".

Comment: If you're willing to start over, I find it easiest to `rm ~/.ssh` on the target and on the client run `ssh-copy-id -i <ssh_key_file> <login>@<target>`.  `ssh-copy-id` will create `~/.ssh` on the target with all the correct permisions.

Comment: I can't thank you enough, it took me one day and found your answer here.

Answer (score 10):

the problem is that windows uses a different *new line* than linux, so when copying the key from windows to linux, there is a **\n** at the end of the line that you can not see on linux in the editor.

If you tail the /var/log/auth.log and try to login, the error is like:

> sshd: error: key_read: uudecode AAAAB3N[....]==\n

If you change your key on windows so its in a single line without a *new line* at the end and copy it then to linux, it should work (did the trick for me).

Comment: this was my problem, but i didn't see anything in auth.log to suggest that was the case. frustrating...

Answer (score 8):

I had to change the ~/.ssh directory permissions from 770 to 700 and the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file permissions from 660 to 600.

For some reason removing group permissions fixed this issue for me.

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 7):

The `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file requires keys to be all on one line. If you added it across multiple lines as in your paste above, try joining the lines.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and now I understand why it is a file, not a directory. However it didn't help.

Comment: for anyone who may be confused by this, what he means is each key itself has to be on a single line, but different keys need to be on different lines.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what worked for me:

In `puttygen`, after you've generated your keys, make sure that you copy and paste the information from the top field to go into your authorized_keys file. If you save your public key to your client machine, and then open it up, the text is different from the text at the top of the `puttygen` screen. Again, make sure that you copy and paste the text from the TOP of the `puttygen` screen (after you've created your keys) into your authorized_keys file which should be located in `~/.ssh`.

Comment: this actually fixed the problem. i dont get why if you click the save the public key why it doesnt save the proper format.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it can be a problem associated with having the public key not on one line, so this approach seems to solve it:

```
echo 'the content of the public key' >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the above answers, make sure you copy and paste the key from `puttygen` correctly!

If you just double-click on the bulk of the key string to select it, you may not get the entire string, because the text box splits lines on some characters, like `+`, such that you don't select the text after the `+` character (which you can't see because the text box is too small).  Be sure to select the entire string manually, from the `ssh-rsa` to the very end of the text box.

Answer (score 1):

for me the problem was i'd created `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` using root so root owned. I had to `chown sshuser:sshuser ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` then it started working

Answer (score 1):

I too faced this error and solved it by changing the permissions of authorized_keys file to `600`.

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 1):

Common error is that people uses text editor (like Vim) and paste the copied text before activating the "insert" (press +i in Vim before pasteing)

Answer (score 1):

If you tried many ways inside `.ssh` and all failed, there is a possibility that you may need to `chmod g-w ~` if you work in a multi-user enviornment.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I changed `authorized_keys`'s permission to `644`, then problem solved.

```
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

to debug open ssh one can use:

```
sudo `which sshd` -p 2020 -Dd
```

it runs sshd on other port 2020. it runs sshd as a current program so output goes to screen. if closed it is closed.

then try to connect.

explanation:

- `which sshd` - locates the sshd address , try execute which sshd see
  what it prints. when using back quotes it executes and returns the
  result in place.
- -p 2020 - specifies port
- -D - log to file
- -d - log to screen

https://www.attachmate.com/documentation/rsit-unix-802/rsit-unix-guide/data/sshd_options_ap.htm

Comment: Could you expand upon this answer? What do the arguments entail? What is the command doing (for someone not experienced)?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on an AWS instance where I had moved /home from the root disk to a new separate disk at xvdf, for free space reasons.

There was nothing in the logs, not under auth or secure, or messages.

In the end I guessed SELinux was the culprit, and some googling lead me to `audit2allow -w -a` which showed a useful error when opening the user's authorized_keys file.

The fix was to run `restorecon -R -v /home`  which relabelled things on the new disk and then selinux was happy to use the user's .ssh/authorized_keys file.

Answer (score 0):

in my case (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS) changing /etc/ssh/sshd_config pubkeyacceptedkeytypes from ssh-rsa to +ssh-rsa worked